# Proxy web socket in shiny server using Apache 2.4

Tags: r, apache, proxy, websocket, shiny-server

I am using the shiny-server (latest version, 1.4.2.786) behind the Apache 2.4, Ubuntu 14.04.

Following the instruction of online documentation (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213733868-Running-Shiny-Server-with-a-Proxy), I can setup the proxy correctly for web sockets. However, I would like to point my URL directly a shiny app (not all apps).

This is my current configuration:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.+)/websocket" "ws://localhost:3838/$1/websocket"
ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:3838/users/username/appname/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:3838/users/username/appname/"
ProxyRequests Off
```

With this configuration, I still get an error message:

```
WebSocket connection to 
'wss://my-url/__sockjs__/
n=WxwgyafTMc2bWeH5eR/787/mx9zqt68/websocket' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 
Unexpected response code: 500
```

I guess this is caused by the configuration of proxy of socket. Thanks for any suggestions to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen [this](https://serverfault.com/a/429406)? It says that your code should look like:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.+)/websocket" "ws://localhost:3838/$1/websocket"
ProxyPass "/users/username/appname/" "http://localhost:3838/users/username/appname/"
ProxyPassReverse "/users/username/appname/" "http://localhost:3838/users/username/appname/"
ProxyRequests Off
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I do want to point my url into my specific directory. Only the websocket is not working in my configuration.

Comment: oh ok. I'll try look for a fix

Comment: I was also having trouble getting direct app link to work appropriately. The app loads, but somewhat sluggishly. That `ProxyPassMatch` bit made me realize where the problem really lies. Thank you.